# How to create GUI components using Ghidra Python Scripting?

Tags: python, scripting, jython, ghidra

Is someone here with experience in developing Python script for Ghidra?
It seems that there is not much information about python scripts, especially for GUI components.
I would like to create some GUI parts using Python2/Jython from Ghidra that will reveal results generated by the script.

Could someone help me with some answers or useful documentation?

I have been trying for a while to study Ghidra Java Scripting Documentation, but I have not been able to find something meaningful.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `CustomTkinter` library for building GUI through Python!
I've never heard of `Ghidra`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need GUI components in the context of Ghidra, inside it.
Btw, Ghidra https://ghidra-sre.org/ is a software reverse engineering (SRE) suite of tools developed by NSA's Research Directorate. Ghidra has its own scripting management based on Jython.